# Adding jQuery plugin to vue component: Uncaught ReferenceError: row is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

The plugin in question is [jquery-drawr](https://github.com/lieuweprins/jquery-drawr).

I am trying to add this sketching component to my Vue single page application in order to allow users to sketch drawings in my app and save them.

But I'm getting the error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: row is not defined

I have added the jquery file under `src/assets/javascripts/jquery.drawr.combined.js` and required it in my component.

And created a component within my Vue project `sketch.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import '../assets/javascripts/jquery.drawr.combined.js';

  export default {

    data() {
      return{

      }
    },


    mounted() {
      const $ = require('jquery');

      $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#canvas").drawr({
          "canvas_width": 600,
          "canvas_height": 600,
          "enable_transparency":false,
        });
        $("#canvas").drawr("start");
      })
    }

  };
</script>
```

Added material icons in my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <!--    sketch component imports-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/3.6.95/css/materialdesignicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
   ...
  </body>
</html>
```

imported jquery in my `main.js` file like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

...

import {$ , jQuery} from 'jquery';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router/router';
import store from './store/store';

...


// USE
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = jQuery;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  store,
}).$mount('#app');
```

This is what I'm seeing:
[image: picture of what I'm seeing]